Unable to find any references for opening of BBS+ signature
I've reviewed the BBS signature scheme and the constant size k-TAA, known as BBS+. However, I couldn't find any specific mechanism for opening in BBS+. In the constant size k-TAA, if a user attempts to authenticate more than k times, they can be traced. Is there a general opening mechanism for BBS+?
